# How apply findall to find several fields | Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to get 2 values from a knowledge base

```
%code, date, amount
values1('AAA', date(02, 03, 2020), 1000).
values1('AAA', date(31, 03, 2020), 2000).
values1('AAA', date(02, 04, 2020), 1350).
values1('BBB', date(15, 04, 2020), 1500).
values1('CCC', date(15, 05, 2020), 950).
```

I want to get the Code and Value by Month in two list. My idea was use findall two times, first to get the Code, and next to get Value, but it's not return the values, just Code.

```
function4(Month, Value, Code) :- 
    findall(Code, values1(Code, date(_, Month, _), _), Code),
    findall(Value, values1(Code, _, Value), Value).
```

I'm newbie on prolog and any advice wuold be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `findall/3` correctly.
For a list of all `Codes`, `Values` in a particular month separately:

```
get_months_data1(Month, Codes, Values) :-
    findall(Code, values1(Code, date(_, Month, _), _), Codes),
    findall(Value, values1(_, date(_, Month, _), Value), Values).
```

```
?- get_months_data1(03, C, V).
C = ['AAA', 'AAA'],
V = [1000, 2000].

?- get_months_data1(04, C, V).
C = ['AAA', 'BBB'],
V = [1350, 1500].

?- get_months_data1(05, C, V).
C = ['CCC'],
V = [950].
```

If you do not want duplicate entries like `['AAA', 'AAA']` above, you can also use `setof/3`.
If you want them `Code, Value` together you can have:

```
get_months_data(Month, Data) :-
    findall(tr(Code, Value), values1(Code, date(_, Month, _), Value), Data).
```

This gives

```
?- get_months_data(03, D).
D = [tr('AAA', 1000),  tr('AAA', 2000)].

?- get_months_data(04, D).
D = [tr('AAA', 1350),  tr('BBB', 1500)].

?- get_months_data(05, D).
D = [tr('CCC', 950)].
```

Comment: Why are you doing this: `findall((Code, Value), ...)`? This looks like a "tuple" but it isn't. Why not use an ordinary pair `Code-Value` or a named flat compound like `tuple(Code, Value)`?

Comment: @TA_intern, A bad habit from haskell, I couldn't shake.

Comment: @TA_intern, Changed to compound

Comment: Great :-) it is harmless with 2 arguments (in most cases) but if you have 3 or more it becomes altogether a different (non-flat) data structure. So this `(a, b, c)` is not the same as a tuple in Haskell. You know it but writing this for the next person reading.

Comment: On the other hand, this name `tr` is completely opaque. I have no idea what it's supposed to stand for. Using such "names" doesn't improve readability IMHO.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie : Just abbreviated transaction, which I assumed is what the initial data represented.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie : I do agree and Pair is a better use here.